# Django deployment over AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to Amazon cloud. I have deployed a django application on AWS EC2. I started the application but unable to see it from the browser. Which IP address will have the access? I tried both private and public but both are not resolved.

Comment: Your app should be accessible at public IP. The private IP is for AWS's local network. What do you see when you visit the public IP?

Comment: how are you running the server means python manage.py runserver?

Comment: i started the server with my private ip python manage.py runserver xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8000

Comment: @MACMAN That's not how it will work. Just for testing, you can try `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and then visit your public ip at port `8000` e.g. `12.34.56.78:8000`. You should see your app. But that's not intended for production. See this blog post for a production level set up: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Try to run you app using command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`.

Your app will be running publicly. Try to figure out IPv4 Public IP in the **Instance** section of AWS.

Then move to **Security Groups** which is listed in left navigation under **NETWORK & SECURITY.**

Choose the security group which is assigned to your instance. After that click on EDIT button on **Inbound** rule section and allow port in which the app is running. For example: port 8000.

**Type**: Custom
**Protocol** : TCP
**Port Range** : 8000
**Source** : Anywhere or My IP

Once added. Click on Save and make sure in Django App settings,allowed host is set to *. So, that you can access your application from anywhere.

**ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']**

The above code is not recommended for production. Good to use for development/testing.